# code to load menu and submenu through jquery dynamic

Tags: jquery, html, css

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ulSub").append('<li id="abc hover" class="DJ hover"><h5>Cancer information</h5><ul id="ulSub1 fadeIn/fadeOut">');
    var ciid = $("#ulSub li").find("ul");
    $(ciid).append('<li><h5>What is cancer</h5></li></ul></li>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="dmenu">
    <ul id="ulSub">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see carefully the above code, hover function i want to implement when i moves mouse on <li> css i had created but how to change dynamically fadeIn/fadeOut and hover using jquery. do you have code to load menu and submenu through jquery...any sample

Comment: ID can't have spaces.

Comment: i know that its mistake ...read next statement sir

Comment: What you really want to achieve is not clear with the code you have tried!!

Comment: i want add hover property add to class in <li> element,just want to append  like class="DJ" after compiling class="DJ hover" just want achieve in .append()

Comment: You shouldn't write comments with "waiting for answer": once you have posted a question, it is implied that you are waiting for an answer to it. The same goes for @RahulDesai: once you answer the OP's question, he is notified, you don't need to comment asking for him to see your answer

Comment: @chiapa: sorry...i dont know the rules for that purpose i mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, use jQuery's `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` functions appropriately.

Working and intuitive code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ulSub").append('<li id="abc hover" class="DJ hover"><h5>Cancer information</h5><ul id="ulSub1 fadeIn/fadeOut">');
  var ciid = $("#ulSub li").find("ul");
  $(ciid).append('<li><h5>What is cancer</h5></li></ul></li>');

  if($("li").hasClass("DJ"))
    $("li").removeClass("DJ");

  $("li").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("DJ");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("DJ");
  });

});
```

```css
.DJ{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dmenu">
  <ul id="ulSub">
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Read up:

- [`.mouseover()` | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
- [`.mouseout()` | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)